# TextField delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange not called for chinese text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have chinese text support in app. I want to restrict 6 character of string in my textfield. But `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method is not being called . This method is called when keyboard is English and its working fine but when keyboard is chinese and i type chinese words method is not being called. Please solve this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue in my App too. May be it's bug of iOS, i don't know.

I used this solution:

1) I made "Editing Changed" IBOutlet from my UITextField to class file.

[image]

2) I described all logic in this `- (IBAction)textFieldDidChanged:(id)sender` method.

3) In your case, it's would be:

```
if (_textField.text.length > 6) {
    _btnNext.enabled = NO;
} else {
    _btnNext.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: you are right but i want that my textfield should not let type more then 6 laters , if it has already 6 laters and try to type another then need to show alert and the action you integrate give me call back after typed value in text field. So i have to do some trick and track old text and then use this. It will be not as strait forward as using shouldChangeCharactersInRange method , but need to use trick

Comment: I understood. But haven't thought about it yet.. May you describe your trick?